# Using new Microsoft account: do I lose all my apps?

Tags: microsoft-account

When I change a Microsoft account, on the new one, do I lose all the apps that I bought with the previous account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your purchases are tied to your Microsoft Account, so if you reset the phone, and set up with a different account, your purchased content/apps/etc. would be lost.

Comment: what if then I reconnect with the first account, do I have the apps back (considering it is fully synchronized)?

Comment: If you set a new phone up (or one that's been reset), your purchased content becomes available again (unless it has been removed from the store, for whatever reason)